# Adding multiple local storage for same site

Tags: javascript, local-storage

[image]

- Under the 'Application' tab of chrome I've found there are multiple localstorage (please see the yellow box) like - `https://stackoverflow.com` , `https://www.google.com` etc.
- I'm now in stackoverflow (#1)
- I'm trying to add a new local storage by the name `https://mytestdomain.com` so I can see it in the yellow box
- I've tried the following javascript code to achieve this

```js
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };  
localStorage.setItem('https://mytestdomain.com', JSON.stringify(testObject));
```

- but it always gets added under the `localstorage` -  `https://stackoverflow.com` (#2, #3). It's not being added as a new `localStorage`

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: It doesn't work like this. What you is a list of websites / domains / frames that are there on the current Chrome tab you are in, and it is showing the local storage data for each one of it.

Comment: Whatever localStorage is generated will be based on your current website. You can not able to generate the localStorage for another site.

Comment: @DeepakKamat, thanks for your comment. I also think so. But when open `facebook.com` in other tab I  can not see this `www.facebook.com` in current tab (stackoverflow). 
Furthermore while I go to the other tab (facebook tab) I do not see these local storeage from the yellow boxe.
B

Answer (score 1):

That yellow box in the image represents all the sites which are storing some data in your localstorage. You cannot add a sitename (i.e `https://mytestdomain.com`) using localstorage.setItem().

Using localstorage.setItem('key', 'val') only set value in current domain's local Storage

If you want some value under `https://mytestdomain.com` domain, there should be a site with url - `https://mytestdomain.com` storing something in your localstorage.

Check here in the official doc for more info - [Documentation Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)